# Google Sheet | Excel | Array Formula + CountIf + Partial Text Problem

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm pretty new with ArrayFormula, have been trying but sometime the formula works, sometimes does not. What I'm trying to do is the combination of ArrayFormula, Countif for searching partial text.

As shown in the worksheet below, there are 10 subjects (column A), each subject has at least one of 4 samples (A,B,C,D) summarized as a string (column B). What I'm trying to do is to find which subject has sample A or B or C or D.

I have tried single formula for each sample, eg cell `D3`

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B3,"*"&$D$2&"*")>0,$A3,"")
```

it returns the correct results. However, when I try arrayformula in cell `I3`,

```
=arrayformula(IF(COUNTIF($B3:B,"*"&$D$2&"*")>0,$A3:A,""))
```

The answers are weird. For example: Subjects (Gamma, Zeta, Eta, Theta) who don't have the sample "A" are shown to have sample "A". And this applies to sample B,C,D too

Not sure what went wrong in here. [Here is the link to the worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x_qALI_BF8M8RZs86P5OIRVKDrKJqLkzWRvPnLyR07w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you using Excel or GoogleSheets? I`ve assumed the latter and removed the Excel tag. What, exactly does "The answers are weird." mean?

Comment: it's google sheet. Subjects (Gamma, Zeta, Eta, Theta) who don't have sample "A" are shown to have sample "A".

Comment: You can apply this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA (IF(REGEXMATCH(B3:B, D2:G2), A3:A,)) `

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Countifs or an array formula. Use `filter` instead. Put this formula in cell `i3`.

```
=Filter(if(REGEXMATCH(B3:B,$D$2),A3:A,""),B3:B<>"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B3:B, ","))="",,
 SPLIT(B3:B, ",")&"×"&A3:A)), "×"))), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"))
```

or use in row 2 if you want to sort it as in your example:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B3:B, ","))="",,SPLIT(B3:B, ",")&"×"&A3:A)), "×"))), 
 "select Col2,max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 
  pivot Col1 label Col2'Subjects'"), {2,3,4,5}, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish all four columns of results with a single formula.

Delete all formulas from I3:L3.

Place the following formula into I3:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(B3:B,I2:L2),A3:A,))`

In plain speech, this read "If anything in B3:B matches a value found in I2:L2, return A3:A in the matching columns(s) at the matching row(s); if not, return null."